# PHP: Round a number upto 2 decimal places and if the number is a whole number then add trailing zeros

Tags: php

**Question**

```
    $number = 153.78999
    $rounded_value = round($number,2);

    $rounded_value will be 153.79
```

What i want is if

```
    $number = 153
```

then

```
    $rounded_value = 153.00
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
sprintf("%0.2f",$number);
```

Check [sprintf](https://www.php.net/sprintf)

or try like this:

```
$rounded_value = number_format($number,2);
```

Check [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: thanks I tried the later one. Perfect! let me accept in 5 mins. It has some time limit before I can accept an answer :) but nice and perfect!

Answer (score 4):

You just want the number format function `$rounded_value = number_format($number,2);`

Answer (score 4):

Simply use

```
$rounded_value = number_format($number,2);
```

Answer (score 3):

`number_format($number, 2, '.', '')`

From the PHP manual, which is a great resource for questions like these: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php